# Export from SQL to MS-Access WITHOUT using the export wizard

Tags: sql, ms-access, export

I want to export from SQL to an MS-Access database.

I DO NOT want to link to SQL Server.

Successful with export using the SQL Import/Export wizard, but this is cumbersome and time consuming and I want to automate the process through SQL Code.

I am willing to use BCP, but have yet to figure out "HOW"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transfer database command.

eg:

```
Sub TestTrans()

  Dim strLocalTable    As String
  Dim strSQLTable      As String
     
  Dim strSQLDataBase  As String
  
  strSQLDataBase = "test3"
  
  strLocalTable = "tblFood2"
  strSQLTable = "tblFood2"
  
  Dim strODBC As String
  
  strODBC = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=ALBERTKALLAL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE="
  
  strODBC = strODBC & strSQLDataBase

  DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database", strODBC, acTable, strSQLTable, strLocalTable
  
End Sub
```

So the above will transfer a single table. If you not using a trusted connection like above, then you can add ;UID=Albert;PASS=MYPASSWORD

## Edit

Of course the above code is run inside of Access. Reading your question again, I see you may well want to do this from SQL server side, and not necessary inside of Access.

Comment: thank you for your comment.  I have done that transfer database inside of Access to transfer tables to SQL.  HOWEVER, I want to do this from the SQL side to EXPORT the SQL Tables so Access can be linked to them with having a link to SQL Database.  I have been playing with BCP this morning, and it seems that this might be the best option as I have not found any other way yet.